# proper authorization redirect in MVC 4 AuthorizeAttribute - hiding unauthorized menu tabs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, kendo-ui, authorization

i'm very close to getting this thing right, but still missing one thing.

in a regular scenario, when authorization fails, something like this happens:

```
filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

this automagically prevents unauthorized MVC menu tabs from rendering (because AuthorizeAttribute is called for each tab that points to underlying authorized resource).

this works as expected. however, i'd like to do something like this:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext ctx) {
            ctx.Result = new ViewResult{ ViewName = "Unauthorized"};
            ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
```

this shows the shared unauthorized view (while keeping the url original so its clear what is unauthorized)

again this works, accept the part of hiding unauthorized menu tabs.

as far as i can tell looking at the [source for HttpUnhandledResult](https://bitbucket.org/tghw/msmvc/src/be8d63e6a8fc/Mvc/HttpUnauthorizedResult.cs) all it does is set StatusCode to 401, which i'm also doing after setting my shard view as result.

yet with my implementation, the un-authorized tabs still show, but i can see in logs that authorization fails for them..

i'm using Kendo Menu (telerik)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up performing a different action depending if authorization was requested for current path, or for a menu item. The way I am differentiating this (in OnAuthorization) is:

```
// are we authorizing current path, or a menu tab?????
_authorizingCurrentPath = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.PhysicalPath.Contains(action);
```

and in HandleUnauthorizedRequest:

```
if (_authorizingCurrentPath)
    ctx.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Unauthorized" };
else
    ctx.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

that way i don't see unauthorized menu items, but if someone still goes there directly, the "Unauthorized" error is shown while preserving the original url.